# How to add javascript function from index.blade LARAVEL to REACT

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, react-native

I got difficulties developing my LARAVEL REACT web-apps

I want to add a javascript function from welcome.blade to my react apps.
fyi my Laravel versions is 5.5 which is support React inside Laravel.

I try to troubleshoot my problem with window.myFunctionHere but no luck, here is my welcome.blade scripts :

```
<div id="example"></div>
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = 0;
    function rangeSlider(){
        $("#harga_filter").ionRangeSlider({
            type: "double",
            grid: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 15000000,
            from: 2000000,
            to: 10000000,
            prefix: "Rp",
            grid_snap: true,
            step: 500000
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

And here is my react scripts :

```
...
    componentDidMount() {
      window.rangeSlider();
    }
...
```

When I run my apps, its produce

> Uncaught TypeError: window.rangeSlider is not a function

Any help will appreciate.

Comment: First, the window doesn't know about `rangeSlider` because you never bound `window.rangeSlider = function()...`.. But really, why not use a `range slider` that's built in React? If you need to use jQuery, think about why you need to use it.

Comment: First>I get this template from my web-designer and the output is html. Second> Im new in javascript such as react. Third> im a backend engineer trying react. Four> Pls help me how to add function from .blade.php into my react apps, or give me alternative to learn. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put that code into method componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
    $("#harga_filter").ionRangeSlider({
            type: "double",
            grid: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 15000000,
            from: 2000000,
            to: 10000000,
            prefix: "Rp",
            grid_snap: true,
            step: 500000
        });
}
```